# Are all eigenvalues of a given complex matrix with variable coefficients real?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a $2 \times 2$ complex matrix $$G(k) = \begin{pmatrix}2\alpha\sigma(\cos k\Delta x - 1)+1 & -i\sigma\sin k\Delta x\\-i\sigma \sin k\Delta x & 4\alpha\sigma(\cos k\Delta x - 1)+1\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to check if all eigenvalues of $G(k)$ are real for all $k \in \mathbb Z$.

If the bottom right element were equal to the top left one, the matrix would be normal, and this would guarantee the reality of the eigenvalues.

The polynom to find the eigenvalues is 
$$\lambda^2 + [6\alpha\sigma(1-\cos k\Delta x)-2]\lambda + [(8\alpha^2-1)\sigma^2\cos^2 k\Delta x -16\alpha^2\sigma^2\cos k\Delta x + 8\alpha^2\sigma^2 + \\ + 6\alpha\sigma\cos k\Delta x - 6\alpha\sigma + 2]$$

As it is a polynom of second degree, I need the discriminant to be positive to make sure the roots are real.

I calculated

$\frac{D}{4} = (1+\alpha^2)\sigma^2\cos^2 k\Delta x - 2\alpha^2\sigma^2\cos k\Delta x+ \alpha^2\sigma^2 - 1$.

I tried estimating it from below only to get that $\frac{D}{4} \geq -(1-\alpha^2\sigma^2)$, so I have no guarantee on it to be positive.

Could you please give me any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The realness of the eigenvalues is not affected if we subtract a real scalar matrix.  Subtract then  $1+3\alpha \sigma (\cos k \Delta x-1)$ from the diagonal, to obtain a matrix of the form

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} -a & b \\ b & a \end{array}\right) $$

The trace is  $0$, therefore the  eigenvalues  are $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$. These are  real if and only if the determinant  $-\lambda^2$ is nonpositive  but the determinant is equal to

$$ - a^2 \sigma^2 (\cos k \Delta x-1)^2 +\sigma^2\sin^2 k \Delta x,$$

and this is nonpositive only for some choices of the parameters.

Comment: May I ask another question then? So, eigenvalues are $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$. If they are complex, they must be complex conjugate (since the polynom of second degree has real coefficients). So we have in that case $-(x + yi) = x-yi$, or $x = 0$. That means that if they are complex, they are purely imaginary, aren't they?

Comment: the eigenvalues of the matrix we obtained after subtracting a real constant  $c$ from the diagonal are $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$. We found that the determinant of this matrix is real, therefore they are both real (nonpositive determinant) or both purely imaginary (positive determinant). The eigenvalues of the original matrix are then $c+\lambda$ and $c-\lambda$.